# Large csv file fails to fully read in to R data.frame

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to load a fairly large csv file into R.  It has about 50 columns and 2million row.

My code is pretty basic, and I have used it to open files before but none this large.

```
mydata <- read.csv('file.csv', header = FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The result is that it reads in the data but stops after 1080000 rows or so.  This is roughly where excel stops as well.  Is their way to get R to read the whole file in?  Why is it stopping around half way.

Update: (11/30/14)
After speaking with the provider of the data it was discovered that they may have been some corruption issue with the file.  A new file was provided which also is smaller and loads into R easily.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: It does sound like you're hitting a memory limit. If you can get the CSV file into a SQLite or MySQL database, you can try to use `dplyr` which will perform many traditional in-memory operations in-database. Alternately, you could try using `sqldf` to read in the CSV partially if you can partition it properly. Lastly, you could always spin up a larger memory instance in AWS, Digital Ocean, etc and perform the analyses there.

Comment: Have a try of "fread" from library("data.table") package.

Comment: @RichardScriven I am using windows server 2003.  
My data must remain on the server for security reasons. the tools i have available at the moment are rstudio, SAS, python, and excel.  I can get things added, but right now that is not really an option if i am to maintain the timeline my group needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, "read.csv()" read up to 1080000 rows, "fread" from library(data.table) should read it with ease. If not, there exists two other options, either try with library(h20) or with "fread" you can use select option to read required columns (or read in two halves, do some cleaning and can merge them back).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using read.table and include the parameter colClasses to specify the type of the individual columns.

With your current code, R will read all data first as strings and then check for each column if it is convertible e. g. to a numeric type, which needs more memory than reading right away as numeric. colClasses will also allow you to ignore columns you might not need.