# Losing Records when writing to csv using R

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have over 27M records of data that I am trying to write to a `.csv` format.
However, I am losing all but 1.1M records when I run my code.  How can I write all 27M records to a `.csv` format without data loss?

```
write.csv(DT, "file.csv")
```

I expect to have all data in a .csv format to upload into a hive schema, but again am only seeing 1.1M records in my schema after running my process.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it hit 1.1M records, or 1.080.000? I would try using `fwrite` instead: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/fwrite

See [Large csv file fails to fully read in to R data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331019/large-csv-file-fails-to-fully-read-in-to-r-data-frame)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried using fwrite and retrieved one additional record 1196191 vs. previous  write.csv method which retrieved 1196190.  Perhaps something is occurring when moving data from desktop to cluster?

Comment: I read the file back into R after writing and all data was there.  This means something is happening when moving from my desktop to hive.  Thanks!